# Turn off auth in ubuntu 19.10 in all components

Tags: 19.10, authentication

How is it possible to turn off authentication everytime when pc wakes up after sleep? I'm just really tired of it, I am often closing my pc and then opening again and everytime Ubuntu requires password.. I know that my pc is used by me only and **I don't need to care about my information safety.** I have already turned off authentication on pc boot. Now I am talking concretically about the "Log in" state after pc sleeping.

And, if it's possible, i'd like to turn off authentication just everywhere in Ubuntu, even when you type command "sudo" in console. **I really don't need to care about my information safety because I don't store any important data on my pc** and it is very hard for me to type password every 5 minutes...

---

Really, it is impossible. If I want to install/update 30 django packages in PyCharm or if I want to install/delete apps via Application Manager I need 30 times enter this password. It is so crazy.

Comment: "I don't need to care about my information safety" Then Linux is not for you. We do care and we do not want others to not care either. So re-install windows? :)  Regarding the lock screen: you can disable it from settings. Install "gnome tweaks" if you have not already.  "If I want  ... I need 30 times enter this password. " That is not correct: password is asked once per instruction; installing or updating 30 pycharms can be done with 1 command so 1 password entry and it also has a 15 minute timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

No prompt on SUDO password.

Try edit `/etc/sudoers` with visudo:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# This entry must be at the bottom to overide any of the above
your_username   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

^O Write Out

^X Exit

The percent sign is used to indicate a group instead of a user.

In addition, any shortcut to a program **must** begin with sudo to make it work, e.g Exec=sudo synaptic-pkexec.

There is no need to delete your password.

Comment: well, it works, but if I run a program without sudo password is still required. Ok, this is good solution I think. Thank you very much, it's funny to play with sudo without password prompt)))

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this in System settings / Screensaver.